# .htaccess particular query redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I wanted to redirect the registration of my website to my forum directory.

My current registration link (in my website) is:

```
mywebsite.com/component/users/?view=registration
```

I want to redirect it to:

```
mywebsite.com/forum/ (or "mywebsite.com/forum" ,without the final slash)
```

I tried traditional methods and they did no work, I also tried .htaccess query redirect but everything I found on the web was about redirecting a query like this:

```
mywebsite.com/something?query=somethingelse
```

but in this particular case, the query is after the "/" so it's not working.

Website is: http://sbenny.com

I hope you guys can help me. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also tried .htaccess query redirect

It sounds like you were already doing the right thing? If your URL path ends with a slash then just end your pattern with a slash...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=registration
RewriteRule ^component/users/$ /forum? [R=301,L]
```

This redirects to `/forum` (without a slash), as you can't redirect to one OR the other. You need to decide which is the canonical.

The trailing `?` on the `RewriteRule` substitution is required to remove the query string from the rewritten URL. A single `?` on the end effectively creates an "empty" query string. The `?` itself does not appear in the rewritten URL.

Comment: I'm sorry it isn't working.. I already tried your method yesterday and it's not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" - do you get an error? Does it do _anything_? Do you have other directives in your .htaccess file? The order is important. The above directives should come at the top of your file, immediately after the `RewriteEngine On` directive (which should only occur once in the file).

Comment: You're right, sorry for my too short reply. The redirect wasn't working because it wasn't at the top of my htaccess file. Now I moved it at the top, the redirect goes to mywebsite.com/forum/?view=registration . The redirect works but I don't like the "?view=registration" at the end of it. Is there a way to change this to mywebsite.com/forum only? Thanks

Comment: Ah yes, a `?` is required on the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution in order to remove the query string from the rewritten URL. (I've updated my answer.)